# Enum as a function parameter

Tags: c++, class, enums, scope

is there anything wrong with this code in c++?

```
enum OpenMode{
    Read = 0x1,
    Write = 0x2,
    Append = 0x4
};

void main(){
    open_file("./something", OpenMode::Write); //!!!!!!!!!
}

void open_file(string name, OpenMode om){
    .
    .
    .
}
```

All i need to do is to pass an enum to function without creating an instance of it.

Ok, Have you ever noticed the way ios works? For example:

```
somefile.open(file_name, ios::in | ios::out)
```

I need a way to do something like this: "something::something"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's something wrong.  The names created by a `enum` go into the scope that contains the `enum`, they are not qualified by the `enum`'s name.

In C++0x, there's a new "enum class" syntax that nests the names within the enum.

A workaround in C++03 is to use a struct or namespace, i.e.:

```
namespace OpenMode
{
    enum OpenMode
    {
        Read = 0x1,
        Write = 0x2,
        Append = 0x4
    };
}

// blah blah OpenMode::Write
```

Unfortunately it also changes the type name to `OpenMode::OpenMode`.

Comment: All good, except you'll need to use commas as the enum value separator.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Thanks, I had blindly copied the original code without fixing it fully.

Answer (score 0):

main's signature should be

```
 int main()
```

or

```
int main(int, char *[])
```

missing comma , in your enum

```
enum OpenMode
{
    Read   = 0x1,  // use commas to delimit enum constants, not semicolons
    Write  = 0x2,
    Append = 0x4
};
```

Comment: There are lots of different parameter types for `main`, but you're right that the return type is required to be `int`.  And right about separating enum values with commas, not semicolons.